# Hey, I am new to ubntu and i tried installing mysql but it did not get installed and instead it is showing this when i do sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates

```
hacker@Windows:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for hacker: 
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease             
Ign:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.73.164.232 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
hacker@Windows:~$
```

Comment: The mysql repo you added does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the repo you added doesn't exist.

The easiest way around this would be to remove that repository and do `sudo apt update` and then install mysql-server from the regular repository via `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Comment: I would also recommend you enabling ubuntu universe and multiverse repositories via `sudo add-apt-repository universe` and `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse`